# How does one graph $\sum_{x=0}^{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, summation, graphing-functions

How does one graph a summation, like $$\sum_{x=0}^{n} n$$

Can it be like this

[image: Summation graph]

Because if you take the points from the summation (0,0), (1,1), (2,3), (3,6) you can tell by summations it only works with integers, so after that integer, like a floor function, it should stay prolonged for one unit until the next integer.

I personally thinks this is how it should be graphed. If this is how the graph looks I think we can easily formulate the integral. If go backwards the limit is 0, in the summations so it's 0.

As for the reason it's like a floor function, if these are fixed points, taking x=1.5, you could just say undefined, but then there's not much you can solve from it. You could say it's discrete, but then is a summation a function, if there is no infinitesimal parts for all x-values, should it just be the way it is?

This may sound off topic, but is there an identity for the integral of any summation, and what is it called? Because if you take $\int\sum_{x=0}^{n} n^n$, you can't find the partial sum for it, so you'll have to introduce another notation.

Comment: I'm not clear what you are plotting the summation as a function of.  It the independent variable is n, than only positive integer values can be taken as arguments.

Comment: Since $x$ only takes integer values, the graph is discrete, just the set of points you list, not the line segments joining them. If you want, you may either then join these vertices (as a piecewise linear function), or draw horizontal line segments (as you did), "for clarity", but these adornments are not part of the graph.

Comment: Can you explain exactly why? If you join the vertices than the values in between are assumed linearly which a partial product proves otherwise. What are suggestions for the summation shown above. Replace n with x and x with n as a function of y.

Comment: Did you mean to write $\sum_{k=1}^n k$ rather than $\sum_{x=0}^n n$?  The latter expression is just $n(n+1)$.  The fact you list the points $(1, 1)$ and $(2, 3)$ suggests that were $n=1$ you want the summation to be $1$ and if $n=2$ then the summation should be $3$.

Comment: @Shawn O'Hare if you take a partial sum, that's correct, but this cannot be used in elementary terms of $\sum_{x=1}^{n} n^n$, and finding the fractional partial sums is way too difficult, you could make a continuity by integers.

Comment: "$\sum_{x=0}^{n} n$" is not a function of $x$ at all (as Shawn O'Hare notes), but rather equal to $n(n+1)$. Generally, a "graph" in the sense of your question contains only points $(x, y)$ with $x$ an element of the domain of the function being graphed. So even if you really meant $\sum_{k=1}^{n} k$, the graph will consist only of isolated points (as StrangerLoop and Andres Caicedo say).

Comment: @StrangerLoop I'm clearly in no position to explain, I have to open up to someone. I appreciate your answer, I'll try to clarify it next time.

Comment: Ok then, it is discrete, I have nothing to back it up with. All I can say is you can see it with isolated points, and you can also see it as some "floor-function". After all, the majority rules :)!

Comment: If you change it to $f(n)=\sum_{i=0}^n i$ then the ordinary step function $S$ is the CDF of $f$. This isn't what you have, but very close so you can think of it in terms of CDFs, if that helps.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One function that will produce the given graph is
$$
  f(x)= \sum_{k=1}^{\lfloor x \rfloor} k = \frac{\lfloor x \rfloor \cdot \lfloor x + 1 \rfloor}{2}
$$
provided $x \geq 0$ and $f(x)=0$ if $x < 0$.  Here $\lfloor x \rfloor$ denonotes the floor function, i.e., decimal truncation.

If you restrict the domain of $f$ to set bounded from above then you can realize it as the finite sum of simple functions, where each simple function is a "step" of the graph.  More specifically, on any interval $(-\infty, x]$ for $x  \geq 0$ we have the functional equality
$$
   f =  \frac{\lfloor x \rfloor \cdot \lfloor x + 1 \rfloor}{2} \cdot \chi_{[\lfloor x \rfloor, x]} + \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor x \rfloor - 1} \frac{k (k+1)}{2} \chi_{[k, k+1)}.
$$
We adopt the convetion that the rightmost sum is $0$ if $\lfloor x \rfloor < 1$.  Here, for any subset $A$ of the real numbers $\chi_A$ denotes the indicator function of $A$, defined by $\chi_A(x)=1$ if $x \in A$ and $\chi_A(x)=0$ if $x \notin A$.  The reason for writing $f$ this way becomes apparent when we want to integrate it. More generally, for a function $g \colon \mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ that can be written as $g = \sum_{k=1}^n \alpha_k \cdot \chi_{I_k}$ for reals $\alpha_k$ we have $\int_{\mathbb R} g(x) \ dx = \sum_{k=1}^n \alpha_k \cdot \lvert I_k \rvert$.

Clearly $\int_{\mathbb R} f(x) \ dx$ is infinite, but for $x \geq 0$
$$
  \int_{-\infty}^x f(t) \ dt = (x - \lfloor x \rfloor) \cdot f(x) +  \sum_{k=0}^{\lfloor x \rfloor -1} f(k).
$$
The rightmost expression is just of the form $\sum_{k=1}^m \left( \sum_{j=1}^k j \right)$ which can be seen to equal $(1/6)m(m+1)(m+2)$.

Comment: Thanks alot,I appreciate the clarification!